# Why can't intrusive_ptr and shared_ptr be used with boost::intrusive containers?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, intrusive-containers

The boost::intrusive documentation describes how [you can use smart pointers with intrusive containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/intrusive/using_smart_pointers.html) but then says you can't use the smart pointers you'd be most likely to use, "It must have the same ownership semantics as a raw pointer. This means that resource management smart pointers (like boost::shared_ptr) can't be used."

Why is this? I can't think of any obvious reason they should be prohibited. What exactly would break? Intrusive containers don't manage allocation of the items inside them anyway. In my case I'd like to use intrusive_ptr, but I don't see any reason why shared_ptr shouldn't work either.

Edit: To be clear, I mean for the hook pointer (e.g. the next pointer in an intrusive singly linked list) to be a smart pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there's a clue in the [documentation for `boost::intrusive::slist`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/intrusive/slist.html#intrusive.slist.slist_container) where it states that with the default configuration, `slist` is stored as a circular list, which precludes using `shared_ptr`/`intrusive_ptr` and friends, because you'd have a reference cycle.

It's still annoying that one part of boost doesn't work properly with another; I guess the only the workaround would be to use something like `intrusive_ptr` and manually bump the reference count when you add an object to the container, and decrement it when you remove it. (This rules out `shared_ptr`, because you can't adjust its reference count directly.)

Answer (score 0):

One obvious reason is efficiency. `shared_ptr` uses atomic increment/decrement operations to count references. This means that disposing large enough container that uses `shared_ptr` pointers under the hood will take seconds, because every reference counter need to be decremented atomically.

Comment: I mention intrusive_ptr which does not have that problem. Also this doesn't really answer the question, which is why the documentation says you can't do it. That's different from whether it may be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this is because intrusive containers already manage the memory internally (like theboost `ptr_` containers), and instead of creating two distinct instrusive container implementations (one for non-owning pointers and one for owning) they decided to put the restriction on what type(s) of point can be used.

Comment: As I said in my question, they don't manage the memory internally. You have to allocate and free items that go into an intrusive container yourself. Adding/removing items from the container performs no allocations/frees and no copies.